# msGraph API from msAccess VBA - Planner plans credentials issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, microsoft-graph-api

I am very new to MS Graph and Office 365 and have made good progress. I am an O365 Global Admin for my organisation (a school) and have app development experience. There is a lot of scope for using MS-Access databases in our context for "globally" managing the O365 content. eg contacts, distribution lists and planner tasks. We want to manage these from an on-premises ms-access database or two and with an admin person authenticating the ms-graph activity, ideally.

So, to test, I created a new db and have managed to get it to consume the following endpoint using VBA but with no user authentication for now.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

However, when I try

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/with my plan id here
```

I get `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

So, clearly my Application registration is wrong or my authentication or both! I have spent hours searching for examples and help and because of the evolving nature of the ecosystem I am finding it pretty hard to work out what I should do now (as opposed to a year or two ago).

The authorisation that generates the access_token that works to allow me access to the groups is:

```
POST 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id here}/oauth2/token

grant_type=client_credentials
client_id={my client id}
client_secret={my url encoded secret}  resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

but using that same access_token for the planner tasks throws the 401 error.

My app permissions look like this:
[image: Azure Portal API Permissions] 
I presume this is because of the difference between the Application and Delegated types but have not fully grasped it all yet. And, I suspect I am using the wrong authentication flow anyway. :-(

So, my questions are:
1. Do my permissions look right?
2. Is my authentication flow correct? Should I be using these instead? ie have I been working from old information?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id here}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id here}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

As you can tell I have become somewhat confused. If anyone can point me in the right overall direction given what I am attempting that would be so helpful.

Thanks so much,
Murray

Comment: Are you sending your access token in the request header?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, like this: `httpReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authToken`. Same for accessing Groups (which works, status 200) and Planner/plans (which throws the 401 status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1. Do my permissions look right?***

Yeah undoubtedly, your azure portal permission seems alright. You need dedicated permission for  that also need to grant admin consent which you have done perfectly shown on screen shot.

***2. Is my authentication flow correct?***

As you are using [`Client Credentials Grant Flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) request format seems alright. But I doubt this flow is suitable for the API you are trying to call. because this API requires dedicated permission.

***3. Should I be using these instead?***

Since this API need dedicated permission you could use [authorization code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

Follow below steps to get your token using `Authorization Code grant flow`

**Get Authorization Code:**

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

**Request Token oauth2/V2.0/token with your code:**

*Request URL:* `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/V2.0/token` Or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/V2.0/token`

*Method:* `POST`

*Request Body Format*

```
client_id:Your_Clinet_Id
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
redirect_uri:Your_Portal_Redirect_URI
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:Your_Client_Secret
code: Paste Code Here
```

**Decode Token:**

You could decode your token on https://jwt.io/ and make sure you have required permission on your azure portal.

***4. Have I been working from old information?***

No, Information has no issue so far I have gone through.

**Note:** For for details implementation of `Authorization Code grant flow` you could take a look [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work through this and report back! Much appreciated. :-)

Comment: No worries , I am here to help you as best I can

Comment: Farid Thanks. Making good progress now. Once I more fully understand what I am doing and formalise my code I will write a more detailed article with code samples for MS-Access VBA. I can now get groups, plans, tasks and contacts so it looks like the authentication and permissions is solved using the `Authorization Grant Flow` as you suggested. :-)

Comment: Done. Yes, thank you. I will add a link to more details over coming days.

Comment: Sure, I will include it on my answer. Thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: For a followup related question (deleted by SO) please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391597/ms-graph-api-does-the-authorization-flow-need-to-start-with-a-browser-call-to-g