# Azure AD. Does the Authorization Flow need to start with a browser call to get the authorization token for desktop apps?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

For background, see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344609/msgraph-api-from-msaccess-vba-planner-plans-credentials-issue/57387556#57387556)

So, the first step in the Authorization Flow is to get the authorization token using a URL in the web browser like this. For a desktop app it needs to have the following signature (I un-encoded it to make it more readable):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

This ends up at the specified redirectURL (assuming I set the same redirectUrl in the Application registration in Azure and authenticated. All good. The response looks something like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=OAQABAAIAAAA...ggAA
```

That code is then used to generate an access_token and a refresh_token using a POST http request from my VBA (MS-Access)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type=authorization_code
client_id={client id}
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
code=OAQABAAIAAAA...ggAA  <== ie the code that was copied from the URL in the Authorization step above
```

That call returns both an access_token (expires in 1 hour) and a refresh_token (default expiry in 90 days). The refresh_token is used to get another access_token after it expires.

So far, so good.

The first step (get the Authorizaion Code) is run in a **browser** and the resulting code is copy-pasted into my App to be used in the second step (to get the access_token). Each time the access_token expires, the refresh_token is used to acquire another access_token AND another refresh_token, giving another 90 days. That all works fine.

**My question is this:**
After 90 days of inactivity both the access_token and the most recent refresh_token will have expired. Is it the case that I will then need to return to the first step, get a new Authorization Code via a browser window, copy and paste the code from the web browser url and use it for the second step?

Is it the case that I will always need to use a web browser to get an Authorization Code or is there some programatic way to do that which I have completely missed?

Thanks.
Murray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the case that I will then need to return to the first step, get
>   a new Authorization Code via a browser window, copy and paste the code
>   from the web browser url and use it for the second step?

Yes, you are right.

> is there some programatic way to do that which I have completely
>   missed?

Yes,  resource owner password credential (ROPC) grant flow allows an application to sign in the user by directly handling their password. The [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) requires a high degree of trust and user exposure and you should only use this flow when other, more secure, flows can't be used.